# Why doesn't each <UL> start from the left when <li> is floating?

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-float

I want my `<li>` elements to be horizontally aligned in each `<ul>` block, but each `<ul>` block to start on the left on a new line.  The following will not work.  The `<ul>`s are shown on the same line.

```html
<style>
  .fl {
    float: left;
  }
</style>

<ul>
  <li class='fl'>Test 1</li>
  <li class='fl'>Test 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class='fl'>Test 3</li>
  <li class='fl'>Test 4</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bcLudxwj/

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ul`s don't start in a new line as you have not cleared the floats for each `ul` block.

Also add a `margin` too to account for the space for the *bullets* of the un-ordered list - see demo below:

update fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xu9j3rsp/

```css
.fl {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
}
ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='fl'>Test 1</li>
  <li class='fl'>Test 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class='fl'>Test 3</li>
  <li class='fl'>Test 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful answers.  Setting `clear:both` on the `UL` element solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Method-1 :Using**  `display: flex;`

Add ul Css `display: flex;` and Remove inline Style in `<ul style='display:block'>` tag.Below Example see

```
ul
{
  display: flex;
}
li.fl
{
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
  list-style-type: none;

}
```

***Live Demo*** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bcLudxwj/4/)

***Snippet Example Below***

```css
ul
{
  display: flex;
}
li.fl
{
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
  list-style-type: none; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class='fl'>Test 1</li>
 <li class='fl'>Test 2</li>
</ul>
<ul >
 <li class='fl'>Test 3</li>
 <li class='fl'>Test 4</li>
</ul>
```

**Method-2 :Using**  `display: table;`

Add ul Css `display: flex;` and Remove inline Style in `<ul style='display:block'>` tag.Below Example see

```
ul
{
  display: table;
}
li.fl
{
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
  list-style-type: none;

}
```

***Live Demo*** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bcLudxwj/6/)

***Snippet Example Below***

```css
ul
{
  display: table;
}
li.fl
{
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
  list-style-type: none; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class='fl'>Test 1</li>
 <li class='fl'>Test 2</li>
</ul>
<ul >
 <li class='fl'>Test 3</li>
 <li class='fl'>Test 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The containers of the elements with float attribute need a "cap" to be correctly used. this cap is usually called "clearer". You need to create a class "clearer" like this in the css:

```
<style>
.clearer {
     clear:both;
  }
</style>
```

And put this `<div class="clearer"></div>` before each `</ul>`

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code :

```
.fl{ float:left;clear:both;}
```

Answer (score 0):

display inline-block for list items and display block for ul

```
ul li{
  display:inline-block;
}

ul{
 display:block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the ul:

```
ul {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```